# C# Напишите программу, которая принимает на вход целое число любой разрядности число и удаляет вторую цифру слева направо этого числа

Tags: c#

Напишите программу на C#, которая принимает на вход целое число любой разрядности число и удаляет вторую цифру слева направо этого числа. И, конечно же, через строку решать нельзя.Есть подсказка, то решить можно через логарифм или через цикл.

Вот все, что я пыталась сделать...

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите число");
int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int l = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Log10(a));
int i = 0;
Console.WriteLine($"{a}  {i} {l}");
int rev = 0, b;
//condition to check if the number is not 0
while (a != 0)
{
    b = a % 10;        //extract a digit
    rev = (rev * 10) + b;   //reverse the digits logic
    a = a / 10;             //remained number
    Console.WriteLine("The reverse of the number is: " + rev  +"  "+a+"  "+b);

}
Console.WriteLine("The reverse of the number is: " + rev);

int tail = rev/10;

Console.WriteLine("The reverse of the number is: " + rev  +"  "+tail+"  "+a);
int x = a;
int y = x;
int i = 0;
int c = 0;

while (y >= 10)    
{
    i++;
    y = y/10;
}
while (c < i)
{
    c++;
    int z = x % 10;
    x = x / 10;
    Console.WriteLine($"{y} {x} {i} {z}");
}
Console.WriteLine($"s{i}");
```

Comment: Добавила код, который удалось сделать

Comment: Непонятно, каким образом показанный код относится к задаче? Видно что он меняет цифры задом наперед. Но в условии задачи это не требуется.

Comment: Была идея развернуть число, записать последнюю цифру в отдельную переменную, удалить 2 последние, добавить ту из переменной и развернуть обратно XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через логарифм как-то так

```
Console.Write("Введите число: ");
int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int digitsCount = (int)Math.Log10(number) + 1; // всего цифр в числе
int multiplier = (int)Math.Pow(10, digitsCount - 2); // множитель предпоследнего разряда
int result = number % multiplier + number / multiplier / 10 * multiplier; // все что справа от разряда + все что слева, делённое на 10
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо огромное!